# React/Socket.io - Client emits to all other clients only once and then only emits to itself after that

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

Running into an issue with React/Socket.io. I have two different socket emitters/listeners: one for a chat, and one for keeping track live changes to the application. I have two separate windows running localhost. The issue is when i emit a change on one window, the other window can receive that change the first time but never again (i.e. get first chat message but none that follow). After that first emit/receive, the sending client starts to receive its own emitters.

front end code: 
`

```
socket = io("localhost:3002");
componentDidMount() {
    //get id from url
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;

    //join specific room for project
    this.socket.on("connect", () => {
      this.socket.emit("room", this.projectId);
    });

    //listener for incoming messages
    this.socket.on("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", (data) => {
      this.props.addChat(this.projectId, data);
    });

    this.socket.on("UPDATE_PROJECT", () => {
      console.log("update");
      this.props.fetchProject(id);
    });
  }
emitTaskChange = () => {
    this.socket.emit("TASK_CHANGE", { data: null });
  };
onChatSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //create object with current user as author, message, and a timestamp
    const chat = {
      author: this.props.currentUser.name,
      message: this.state.newChat,
      createdAt: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    };

    //send message through socket
    this.socket.emit("SEND_MESSAGE", chat);

    //call action creator to add new chat
    this.props.addChat(this.projectId, chat);

    this.setState({ currentMessage: "" });
  };

handleTaskEdit = (taskId, currentStatus) => {
    const newStatus = currentStatus === "todo" ? "inprogress" : "completed";
    this.props.editTask(this.projectId, taskId, newStatus);
    this.emitTaskChange();
  };
```

`

backend code: 
`

```
const io = socket(server);

//create separate chat rooms using project id
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("room", (room) => {
    socket.join(room);
    socket.in(room).on("SEND_MESSAGE", (message) => {
      socket.emit("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", message);
    });
    socket.in(room).on("TASK_CHANGE", (data) => {
      socket.emit("UPDATE_PROJECT", data);
    });
  });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

found the error: 
had to change the server-side code from `socket.on` and instead use the io object that was initialized such as `io.sockets.on`